# Docker port mapping weirdness

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  mautrix-wsproxy:
    container_name: mautrix-wsproxy
    image: dock.mau.dev/mautrix/wsproxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 29331
    environment:
      #LISTEN_ADDRESS: ":29331"
      APPSERVICE_ID: imessage
      AS_TOKEN: put your as_token here
      HS_TOKEN: put your hs_token here
      # These URLs will work as-is with docker networking
      SYNC_PROXY_URL: http://mautrix-syncproxy:29332
      SYNC_PROXY_WSPROXY_URL: http://mautrix-wsproxy:29331
      SYNC_PROXY_SHARED_SECRET: ...

  mautrix-syncproxy:
    container_name: mautrix-syncproxy
    image: dock.mau.dev/mautrix/syncproxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      #LISTEN_ADDRESS: ":29332"
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:pass@host/mautrixsyncproxy
      HOMESERVER_URL: http://localhost:8008
      SHARED_SECRET: ...
```

But then `docker ps` shows

```
... dock.mau.dev/mautrix/wsproxy ... 0.0.0.0:49156->29331/tcp, :::49156->29331/tcp
```

And I have to use external port 49156 to connect to its internal port 29331.

Where the heck did this 49156 come from? How do I map it so it's 29331->29331 ?

`docker inspect` shows:

```json
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": ...,
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "29331/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49156"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49156"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the provided answers, if you want a fix port mapping, you can do this by providing 2 ports separated by a colon with the [publish](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) flag or in the [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) array when using compose. The left part is the mapped port available on the host system, and the right part is the port inside the container.

```sh
# make port 29331 inside the container available on port 8080 on the host system
docker run --publish 8080:29331 busybox
```

In your case, to answer your question.

> How do I map it so it's 29331->29331 ?

```yaml
services:
  mautrix-wsproxy:
    ports:
      - "29331:29331"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for `ports` in a compose file (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) we can read the following:

> #### Short syntax
>
> There are three options:
>
> ...
>
> - Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port).
>
> ...

This means in essence that a random, free host port is chosen.

To explicitly map the container-port on a known host-port (even if it s the same as the container port), we use the `HOST:CONTAINER` syntax (see link above):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mautrix-wsproxy:
    ...
    ports:
      - "29331:29331"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for `ports`:

> There are three options:
>
> - Specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER)
> - Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port).
> - ....

You're using the 2nd option, and just specifying the container port that you want to expose.  Since you didn't specify a host port to map that to, "*an ephemeral host port is chosen*".